# Какие модули использовать для чата на Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, сокет, поиск-библиотек

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой питоновский модуль или стороннюю библиотеку использовать для реализации чата на сокетах?

И в чем разница между ванильными модулями `socket` и `socketserver`?

Может, есть хорошие библиотеки под мою задачу?